# How can I use ember-simple-auth to set header in custom url api with ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

My ember data model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import config from './../config/environment';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...

  useRepairPackage(repairPackageId) {
    this.get('session').authorize('authorizer:digest', (headerName, headerValue)=> { 
      const headers = {}; 
      headers[headerName] = headerValue; 
      Ember.$.ajax({url: `${config.host}/${config.namespace}/quotations/${this.get('id')}/use_repair_package.json`, type: "PATCH", headers: headers}).then((result)=> { 
        return this.reload();
      }); 
    });
  }
});
```

I check `ember-simple-auth` document, I found this way to add session in header. But it can not work in `model`, and how can I add the seesion in this action? Thanks.

Comment: It's a bad design. You shouldn't do such things as authorization in model. Actions should be on routes/controllers.

Comment: @GennadyDogaev Ok. I think it must set in route.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the session service to the model and then access it.

export default DS.Model.extend({
   session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

And now access the session below inside to send the session data.